# Windows server 2012 r2 Unexpected shutdown everytime when trying to restore database

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012

Why my windows server always shuting down when i'm trying to restore database ? is this because the data is corupt ? what is the common issue that create this behaviour ? I have 3 db that i tried to restore the other 2 is sucessfull restored, but when i tried the third db my windows server will shutdown . My Original backup db is 900MB and it will expand to 60gb after it succesfully restored. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Who knows. What do the event logs on the server say about the shutdown?

Comment: event id 6008 , it dont tell me much, it just says windows has unexpected shutdowns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks its my ram that not big enough, my previous ram is 16gb and then i upgrade my vm ram to 24 gb and it work well.